# Why does perl LWP module can reach website only when cipher_list is defined?

Tags: perl, ssl

I have an AIX 7 server where I perl scripts can reach a web server only if I define in the script the cipher list.
As you can see in this example:

```
$ perl -e 'use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug3);
    IO::Socket::SSL->new(SSL_hostname => "", 
      PeerAddr=>"<hostname>:<port>", 
      Proto=>"tcp",
      SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
      SSL_version => TLSv1_2
      )or die $!'
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2853: new ctx 537100552
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:692: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:694: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:717: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:753: not using SNI because hostname is unknown
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:819: call Net::SSLeay::connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:822: done Net::SSLeay::connect -> 0
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:870: connection failed - connect returned 0
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:871: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:871: local error: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
DEBUG: ...ulti/IO/Socket.pm:48: ignoring less severe local error 'IO::Socket::IP configuration failed', keep 'SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure'
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2875: free ctx 537100552 open=537100552
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2886: OK free ctx 537100552
SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure      ...propagated at -e line 1.
```

I tried other protocols, all failed. If needed I can include other examples for those. Manual connection so from command line with `openssl`, `curl` or `wget` works without problem.

If the cipher_list included in the perl one-liner then the perl works fine. I just don't understand why I need to define this list explicitely. Is there any way to avoid the need to directly code in the script a cipher list?

Example for working version:

```
$ perl -e 'use IO::Socket::SSL qw(debug3);
    IO::Socket::SSL->new(SSL_hostname => "", 
    PeerAddr=>"<hostname>:<port>", 
    Proto=>"tcp",
    SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
    SSL_version => TLSv1_2,
    SSL_cipher_list=>"ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
  )or die $!'
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1829: new ctx 29289008
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:475: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:477: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:495: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:533: not using SNI because hostname is unknown
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:566: Net::SSLeay::connect -> 1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:621: ssl handshake done
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1866: free ctx 29289008 open=29289008
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1874: OK free ctx 29289008
```

Module versions are not outdated, I checked those.
Net::SSLeay version: `OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019`

Comment: This is not a normal situation. Are you having trouble reaching any server, or a particular server? If it's a particular server, is it some legacy thing with limited or outdated support for SSL?

Comment: A particular server. I don't really have access to it, just need to verify connection, but I asked for information about it, so the most reasonable cause is that the webserver is outdated?

Comment: If you only have problem with that particular server and your LWP is fine with other servers, then yeah, I'd investigate the server. Also, you might turn on debugging in curl to see what it does to set up the handshake.

Comment: *"Module versions are not outdated, I checked those. Net::SSLeay version: OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019"* - that's not the Net::SSLeay version but the version of OpenSSL - which is pretty outdated. OpenSSL 1.0.2 is out of support since more than a year. But this is likely not the source of your problem.